# How to set up navigation on a multilayer telegram menu?

Tags: go, architecture, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to set up navigation on a multi-level menu in Telegram.
But I cant add Callbacks in vars, because its generate loop
I need to save condition of user, on which page he is now and which button on page him press

I downt know what to write more, I am using tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5, no good example in github

ChatGPT cant hep in this question :(

```
package main

import (
"log"

tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)

type Page struct {
Name     string
Buttons  [][]tgbotapi.KeyboardButton
Parent   *Page
Children []*Page
Callback func(update tgbotapi.Update, page *Page, bot *tgbotapi.BotAPI)
}

func sendPage(ChatID int64, page *Page, bot *tgbotapi.BotAPI) {
buttons := tgbotapi.NewReplyKeyboard(page.Buttons...)
message := tgbotapi.NewMessage(ChatID, page.Name)
message.ReplyMarkup = buttons
_, err := bot.Send(message)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error sending message: ", err)
}
}

var (
mainMenuPage = &Page{
    Name: "Главное меню",
    Buttons: [][]tgbotapi.KeyboardButton{
        {
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Профиль"),
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Кошелек"),
        },
        {
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Пустая кнопка"),
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Фидбек"),
        },
    },
    Parent:   nil,
    Children: []*Page{},
    Callback: nil,
    }
)

var (
    profileMenuPage = &Page{
        Name: "Профиль",
        Buttons: [][]tgbotapi.KeyboardButton{
            {
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Мой профиль"),
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Статистика"),
        },
        {
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Добавить кошелек"),
            tgbotapi.NewKeyboardButton("Назад"),
        },
    },
    Parent:   nil,
    Children: []*Page{},
    Callback: nil,
}
)

func main() {
// Определение бота и создание канала для получения обновлений
bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI("token")
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
bot.Debug = true
log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
u.Timeout = 60
updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

sentMainMenu := false

// Обработчик обновлений
for update := range updates {
    if update.Message != nil {
        // Обработка сообщений от пользователя
        msg := tgbotapi.NewMessage(update.Message.Chat.ID, update.Message.Text)
        bot.Send(msg)

        // Отправляем главную страницу меню только при получении первого обновления
        if !sentMainMenu {
            sendPage(update.Message.Chat.ID, mainMenuPage, bot)
            sentMainMenu = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```